# Do Christian concepts of fellowship allow for a congregation to welcome atheists to participate in their community?

Tags: religious-practice, atheism, fellowship

Due to family issues, I have come to distance people from me, mainly because the family issues made me a rough person and I am not "easy" to hang around. For the same reasons, I was never close to the Church or God. Now, being an adult and understanding the world, I find it hard to believe in any kind of religious creed. I am, in fact, an atheist.

My question here is: is it considered *wrong* (by the same religious communities) to seek the company of religious communities (for example, going to the meetings of Jehovah's Witnesses) if it's for the sole purpose of feeling less lonely?

*I am not excluding that I may, with time, find that particular religion suitable for me.

Comment: Hi Con7e! That is a good question, however this falls more under pastoral advice or "Is X a sin?" type questions, which don't really fit our format. It'd probably be best to ask the leader of whatever group you're interested in joining.

Comment: In the current form, this question isn't really answerable here. We don't answer [truth questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527/20). This could also be seen as a pastoral advice question, which we don't answer, either. For an academic answer, you could change it to ask whether a specific Christian denomination permits non-believers to attend, but I suspect you aren't really looking for an academic answer.

Comment: On a more personal level, practically any Christian church *ought* to welcome non-believers and even atheists. Sharing our community with others, that they may see the love of Christ and come to their own faith, is one of the most important aspects of Christianity. However, there are groups of Christians which differ in this view, and unfortunately may be more hostile to non-believers.

Comment: I am torn, because as a Christian, I want to welcome you and encourage you to participate if for no other reason then that is what Jesus would have me do. Unfortunately, this is an academic site that doesn't study what is true, as much as how people study Truth.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not answerable on this website. I tried to give it a shot anyway... my bad for not reading the rules. @Flimzy indeed, I am not seeking for an academic answer-

Comment: It seems, however, that you do embrace a creed, specifically the atheistic creed that there is no God.  I would wonder what evidence you found that convinced you of this ideology/philosophy.

Comment: Why do you say this @Narnian ? I said atheism because it's what better represents my current "status". I am currently in the "default" mode, the mode we are were when we were too young to believe in anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types. I hope to see you post again soon. Plenty of us would be happy to discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) if you want.

Comment: Since you mentioned Jehovah's Witnesses, you can ask for their opinion specifically. We can answer that.

Comment: @Con7e Why would the default mode be atheism?  Atheism does believe something very specific.  Agnosticism would be more appropriate.

Comment: Since you are asking about "Christian concepts" generally, you'd probably be safe changing the question to, essentially, "Do to scriptures encourage or discourage non believers to participate in Christian services and participate in the Christian community?" This would be readily answered.  If you had specific questions about how you might be able to participate in their community, a follow up question asking specifically about that community would be fine as well.

Comment: If you are an athiest then wouldnt you rather be alone than listen to and interact with dillusional (from the perspective of an athiest) people? Why not join a bowling group or such?

Comment: @Con7e What you're describing does indeed sound less like atheism ("God does not exist" or "God cannot exist"), and more like agnosticism ("I don't know whether or not God exists","God may exist but I don't agree with any formulation about God","God is not part of my vocabulary but may become so if I'm sufficiently convinced").

Answer (score 10):

> Do Christian concepts of fellowship allow for a congregation to welcome atheists to participate in their community?

In the most general terms, **yes** - most congregations are open to non-member participation.  Saying that, it is possible different congregations have a nuanced stance in this regard - some of their meetings may be closed and it is best to ask the leaders of an individual community what their stance is.  Another consideration is that while a particular meeting may be open to non-members, some of the practices engaged in may be restricted to member (or visiting Christian) participation - e.g. taking Holy Communion - so your participation may be partial in that respect (as would be appropriate considering you would not believe all that the congregation members believe with respect to those practices).

Answer (score 4):

From the point of view of a Seventh-Day Adventist, we welcome unbelievers, because many in the church have come from Atheism. You would be welcome with open arms.

Answer (score 4):

In the Christian and Missionary Alliance Church (C&MA) of which I am a member, you would definitely be welcome when attending almost any gathering of church members, whether large or small, plenary or small group.

Our church has "ministries" for almost every age group and for almost every conceivable interest or need (e.g., divorce recovery, 12-step meetings for a variety of addictions, senior citizens, college and career, single parents, grief counselling, church membership classes, growth groups, and many more).

Even if you are simply a disinterested observer, or are there to enhance your social life, you would be welcomed, accepted, and loved.

Does this mean you are therefore free to "sow seeds of discord," or to proselytize, so to speak, for atheism? Of course not. Honest, open, and even heated discussions are encouraged in my church, but as in most every place besides church (except the Jerry Springer show!), good manners are *de rigueur*.

Does this mean that every C&MA church will be as equally welcoming? Probably not. Despite a shared denominational identity, each local church within the denomination has its own culture, norms, mores, and folkways. Rest assured I am not making excuses for churches in my denomination which are not as accepting of atheists (for example), but I'm just being realistic about regional and cultural differences, whether in the US or abroad.

By the way, I'm familiar with one local church in the Episcopalian denomination which has an Alpha Course for seekers who are interested in finding out more about the Christian faith. Who knows, there you might even meet another nonbeliever of the opposite sex with whom you can strike up a friendship!

In conclusion, all local Christian churches should--ideally--be welcoming of strangers and non-members, but we live in a far from ideal world. Nevertheless, I encourage you to seek out a local church which has an open door policy and welcomes seekers of all stripes, even atheists. When you find one, however, do not expect perfection, just a bunch of imperfect Christians, all of whom are under construction. In other words, be willing to show the same respect, courtesy, and patience they show to you.

Comment: I attend a C&MA church for many years with a small group focused on Older Couples mentoring Younger Newlyweds. There were 10 couples, and 4 of them did not attend the church. 2 of them were Catholics, and 2 of them were Atheists, but they said the ideas being taught (from the Bible) made sense and they found those discussions to be beneficial to them. There was never a word about their religious affiliation. In fact one of the Atheist couples offered their house and pool for a Baptism ceremony and the church accepted. As others have said this is not always the case, and depends on the church.

Comment: @Mark: Sounds like your church has its head screwed on straight. Wish they were all like that. My church's mission statement is "Following Jesus in Diverse Community," and our membership rolls reflect a highly diverse group of people. If you'd like to check out our church's website, it can be found at acac.net. The Lord bless you. Don

Answer (score 3):

### A Catholic Official Position

Catholics absolutely welcome atheists or anyone else to attend Holy Mass. Unfortunately, as suggested elsewhere, we do not feel it is appropriate for most non-Catholics to receive Holy Communion. For example, a norm developed by the [National Conference of Catholic Bishops](http://www.usccb.org/prayer-and-worship/the-mass/order-of-mass/liturgy-of-the-eucharist/guidelines-for-the-reception-of-communion.cfm) (later the U.S. Conference of Catholic Bishops) reminds its readers of the Catholic belief that "the celebration of the Eucharist is a sign of the reality of the oneness of faith, life, and worship", and states:

> **We also welcome to this celebration those who do not share our faith in Jesus Christ**. While we cannot admit them to Holy Communion, we ask them to offer their prayers [or, if one does not believe in the efficacy of prayer, simply their hopes and thoughts] for the peace and the unity of the human family.

(emphasis added)

It is often the case, for a few possible reasons, that even a practicing Catholic attending Mass will not receive Holy Communion either; so one who is not Catholic, Christian, or even theist should not feel left out.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it isn't wrong to fellowship with other human beings. Just remember that it may take some time to find a group who feels the same way, but it will be worth it. Look for the enlightened ones who welcome you with open arms.

Comment: Welcome, CJane! Unfortunately I don't see that this is an answer to the question. The question asks whether particular religious communities consider "seeking fellowship" wrong; you haven't addressed that at all. You can [edit](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/31304/edit) your answer to try and address that more directly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This site is different than what you were probably expecting. Please read [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) I hope to see you post again soon.